# Real GDP data for India

Tags: gdp

I am having quite a bit of trouble finding data on India's GDP in REAL terms.
I would appreciate it if someone knew a website/database that might have this information.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fred has [the data](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/NAEXKP01INQ652S) on the real GDP of India, also they source it from OECD so you should be able to get it there as well.

[image]